# ScrollView Error

Tags: android, view, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I have a scrollview which has a linearlayout as a child . now when i launch my app i get the following error

```
03-11 10:58:35.723: E/AndroidRuntime(6261): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
03-11 10:58:35.723: E/AndroidRuntime(6261):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3654)
03-11 10:58:35.723: E/AndroidRuntime(6261):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3525)
03-11 10:58:35.723: E/AndroidRuntime(6261):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3482)
03-11 10:58:35.723: E/AndroidRuntime(6261):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3462)
03-11 10:58:35.723: E/AndroidRuntime(6261):     at android.support.v4.app.NoSaveStateFrameLayout.wrap(NoSaveStateFrameLayout.java:40)
03-11 10:58:35.723: E/AndroidRuntime(6261):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:915)
03-11 10:58:35.723: E/AndroidRuntime(6261):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
03-11 10:58:35.723: E/AndroidRuntime(6261):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
03-11 10:58:35.723: E/AndroidRuntime(6261):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
03-11 10:58:35.723: E/AndroidRuntime(6261):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransaction
```

below is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >   

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/info_linearlayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
     .......................
     ...................

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

below is my java code where i get the scroll view an then get the relative layout

```
oScrollView =  (ScrollView) LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.eyefeedinfo, null);
                    EyeFeedWizard.m_oInfoPage = (LinearLayout) oScrollView.findViewById(R.id.info_linearlayout);

                    /
                    oCurrentPage = EyeFeedWizard.m_oInfoPage;
```

Comment: can you paste java code?

Comment: Why you use scrollview like this ?

Comment: actually im using scroll view in a Viewpager wwhere my activity setcontents VIewpager and then call pageradapetr which returns a page which has the above scrollview